Are there any examples of superposition other than double-slit (or similar) experiment, which we can actually visualize?
When we do double slit experiment (or its variations) superposition can be seen as an interference pattern on a detector, which is very easy to express mathematically, visualize, or even directly observe, as the observable is an actual position in space. So we can literally see the spatial distribution of the particles.
However, it is hard for me to think of any other example, where you can visualize (even mathematically) the effects of superposition (similar to interference pattern, but not necessarily). I realize, that the states need to be non-orthogonal for such effect to be nonzeo, but all the physically relevant "common" states, such as, spin, energy, etc. are usually orthonormal. Thus, I am asking whether there are any other (maybe nontrivial) examples.

Waves in a ripple tank come to mind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_tank

There are many kinds of interferometers that aren't that difficult to visualize. Some of the simplest ones are the Michelson interferometer and the Mach-Zehnder interferometer
These are basically systems where a light beam is split, and each beam takes a different length path to the detector, leading to constructive or destructive interference depending on the difference in path lengths.
The whole field of interferometry is more or less finding applications for superposition and interference, so you could go through all the different interferometer types and see which ones you can and can't visualize --- then study or experiment with them until you can visualize some that you previously couldn't.
